# How to query large numbers of Akka actors and store results in a database?

Tags: scala, akka

I am building a securities trading simulator in Scala/Akka. Each `TraderActor` has a `var wealth` that fluctuates over time as the actor trades via the market.

At various time intervals, I would like to query all of the `TradingActors` to get the current value of their respective 'wealth' and store all of the results in a database for later analysis. How might I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querying million of actors to retrieve the value that they have is not a good idea because

- whenever you get the entire aggregated value, those value will be stale.
- You can not have realtime report

So, you need kinda distributed eventing system like Kafka to push the value to that upon any change. Then you can define consumer of Kafka which subscribed to it and receive events and aggregate or visualise etc. 
In this way you will have live reporting system without setting up any cronjob to periodically goes through actors and retrieve their state.

Comment: I called it "reporting" just to make it more tangible, of course, instead of report those states or visualise, you may store them in database. The point is that you can do whatever you want with those value easily.

Comment: I am concerned about data going stale during the query process. You seem to be advocating a push model for the data? Is this the [Kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/) that you refer to? I don't understand who/what is consuming Kafka output?

Comment: Yes, you can have another layer in your application like another actor system which consume the events that have been pushed by your aforementioned actors in kafka or any other queuing system like rabbitmq. In advanced model you can even have completely isolated system consisting cluster of actors subscribed to distribured queue system and consume events and does the persistence.

Answer (score 1):

I would send a `StoreMessage` that would tell the `TraderActor`s to send their `wealth` value to a `StoreController` actor ref through some `StoreData` message.

The `StoreController` would then receive the `StoreData` messages and either store their content as they are received, or route them to a `StoreWorker` that would store them as they are received (making `StoreController` a router), or stack them before writing them, or any other strategy that suits your needs.

The way you want the `StoreController` to handle the received `wealth` mostly depend on your database, the number of `TraderActor`s, how often you would like to store the values, etc.

Comment: @JeanLogheart Do you have any recommendations for

Answer (score 0):

I think the [event bus](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/event-bus.html) implementation that comes with Akka is there for this very purpose.